# Segurança do Meu Projeto Intranet

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, iis

Tenho um projeto intranet comercial, porem como validar para que esse meu projeto não seja copiado da pasta raiz, de onde o IIS executa? Pois assim se meu cliente tiver um conhecimento ele facilmente poderia copiar meu sistema jogar no pendrive e revende-lo, estou certo? **Que tipo de segurança devo utilizar para projetos intranet**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiramente o diretório do seu IIS precisa ser configurado para ser acessado apenas com o perfil do seu usuário ... E a partir do momento que você da um "publish" na aplicação, o código é compilado e são gerados arquivos diferentes, o que não possibilita a edição. Porém se ele tiver acesso a sua pasta raiz do IIS não vejo como impedir que ele copie e cole a aplicação para publicar em outro IIS.

Comment: Acredito que fazendo como falou em deixar o diretório apenas acessível para meu usuário, vai ser de grande ajuda!

Comment: O IIS também permite que o usuário possa impedir que alguns arquivo sejam acessíveis por URL, então se existir algo importante em algum arquivo .xml com senhas ou algo do tipo é possível bloquear o acesso a esse arquivo através do IIS.

Answer (score 1):

O seu projeto tem ligação permanente à internet?
Se tiver, pode validar a execução da aplicação num servidor seu. Por exemplo validar uma "*secret-key*" que estará no código da sua aplicação contra um IP ou um *hostname* que estará definido no seu servidor.

Atualização:
Se não tiver acesso à internet, pode fazer a validação no próprio código, por exemplo verificar se o *hostname* que o executa é o único que está autorizado.

Atualização (2):
Pode usar:

```
System.Net.Dns.GetHostName
ou
Environment.MachineName
```

E verificar se isso corresponde ao nome da máquina que está autorizado a executar a aplicação.

Comment: Poderia me explicar de maneira mais detalhada o caso de não ter acesso a internet?

Comment: Atualizei a resposta para responder à sua questão.